# How to sort a file with bash

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, lts, sort

I have a file with one word on each line and I want to sort the file alphabetically.  There's 2050 words in the file, so doing it manually would take a long time.  Is there a bash script to sort it alphabetically and rewrite it to the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's `sort [file name]`. That prints the sorted list to your terminal. If you want to redirect it to a file you can do `sort [original file] > [sorted file]`. If you have items starting with numbers, you can do `sort -h` insted of sort for a more intuitive sorting.